# Difficulty in understanding interceptors headers

Tags: angular2-forms

why we are adding headers in interceptors?I have gone through several websites and I can't understand

Answer (score -1):

Adding headers is not the purpose of interceptors. Header manipulation is just one of the things you **can** do in interceptors IF the need arises. It's up to you to use them if/when you need to.

Examples I've used interceptors for:

- Adding client-side caching functionality for certain specific service calls.
- Faking a back-end call for a demo application such that the http call does not go through with the full call to the server.

The [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) provides an explanation and a few examples including ensuring that requests are made via HTTPS, some help with authentication settings, and manipulating request bodies.

Comment: Why the downvotes on the answer? It addresses the question asked.